# Showing empty rows in a gridview along with filled rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to show 4 rows in a gridview. If i have 2 rows in Database, i should show 2 filled rows and 2 empty, if i have 4 in database, show 4 filled rows and if i have none in the database, show 4 empty rows. How is this possible?

I am using SQl Server 2005 using c#, Asp.Net. I want to use a stored procedure to get results from database using datasets and then binding to the gridview.

I would like to know the logic so i can try writing code for myself. Hope i am clear and i hope what i am asking is possible?!

Thank you!

Comment: Try do a bit more of your own research next time, but I posted an answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this is using the CreateRow() method of the gridview class, as in

```
gridView1.CreateRow(int rowIndex, 
                    int dataSourceIndex, 
                    DataControlRowType rowType, 
                    DataControlRowState rowState);
```

So create four of these using a standard `for` loop, then append the required rows to the relative row in the gridview. As in like gridview.Row[i] = SelectedDataBaseRow or something, it would be something (if you are using datatables) along the lines of

```
gridView1.SelectRow(i) = dataTable1.Row[i].ItemArray[columnindex].ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your stored proc simply create some sort of left or right join to produce the empty rows by matching against a common column. For example, consider this:

```
DECLARE @table AS TABLE
    (
      one VARCHAR(20) ,
      two VARCHAR(30) ,
      some_key INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @table
        ( one, two, some_key )
VALUES  ( 'a', 'b', 1 )

SELECT  t.one ,
        t.two ,
        t.some_key
FROM    @table t
        RIGHT JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS id
                     UNION
                     SELECT 2
                     UNION
                     SELECT 3
                     UNION
                     SELECT 4 AS id
                   ) x ON x.id = t.some_key
```

Will produce

```
one    two  some_key
a      b    1
NULL   NULL NULL
NULL   NULL NULL
NULL   NULL NULL
```

You can then bind the resultset to your gridview.